# How can I get an angle not a normal value for a random number

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I try to create a random number and I want to get the angle like in the code below

```
but I always got a number not an angle between 0 and 180
```

Fortran

```
!Now start determining the angle
    !First angle theta1 is Va*rab =|Va|*|rab|*cos(theta1)
    !First I can determine Va*rab and call it V1 then |Va|*|rab|and call it V2 then calculate the angle
    !V1=(a2*a4)+(b2*b4)+(c2*c4)

    V1=(a2*a4)+(b2*b4)+(c2*c4)
    write(10,*) 'v1',V1
    V2=(Va*rab)
    write(10,*) 'V2',V2
    theta1 = acos(V1/V2)
    print*, 'The angle 1 is ',theta1
```

Answer (score 0):

The acos function (and its "friends") all work with radians.

From the satndard:

16.9.4 ACOS (X)

1. Description. Arccosine (inverse cosine) function.
2. Class. Elemental function.
3. Argument. X shall be of type real with a value that satisfies the inequality |X| ≤ 1, or of type complex.
4. Result Characteristics. Same as X.
5. Result Value. The result has a value equal to a processor-dependent approximation to arccos(X). If it is real
   it is expressed in radians and lies in the range 0 ≤ ACOS (X) ≤ π. If it is complex the real part is expressed in
   radians and lies in the range 0 ≤ REAL (ACOS (X)) ≤ π.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you well

Comment: He means your `theta1` in your code is in radians, but your comment that you want it between 0 and 180 suggests that you're thinking in degrees, not radians. So you need to convert.

Comment: But the number that I got for V1 and V2 if I measure them by using a normal calculator, it gave me the right angle but her in the program give me a number like 1.57 or 1.65 
So How can I transform them

Comment: your calulator is set up to use angles in degrees (`DEG` sign). you would need to change your calulator to RAD (using radians).

Comment: conversion is done via `angle_rad = angle_deg * PI / 180`.

Comment: Now You mean that the number I got for theta, I will multiply with 180/Pi or I understood wrong.

Comment: I have a problem that the program doesn't read the V1 and V2 correct

Comment: "I have a problem that the program doesn't read the V1 and V2 correct" did you mean "write"? From your code snippet we cannot see how you got the initial values of a2 / b2 / c2 etc and VA and rab, So please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No sorry I was wrong, Now it is working well Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Replace the radians based ACOS

```
theta1 = acos(V1/V2)
```

With the degrees based ACOSD

```
theta1 = acosd(V1/V2)
```

Comment: I would recommend NOT to use this solution - ACOSD is not part of standard Fortran. and so you are relying on your compiler to suport it as an extension